# SmartCard cannot get ATR

Tags: smartcard

When I insert the card, the VCC and IO pin have been pulled HIGH, the clock pulse has been also provided as the configuration, but I am not able to receive ATR through I/O pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should test to be sure your card is synchronous card or asynchronous card. The way they return ATR is different. Read ISO-7816 to get more information.

Comment: More exactly: memory (= synchronous) cards have no ATR at all, but one may be synthesized by the software to satisfy API conventions as for PCSC, an approach also used for contactless cards.